# non-static variable cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, static, non-static

i have read similar issues on here, but i still can't figure out how to fix my code.  i am testing a timer and while i can put the timer output in the command line while the gui opens in seperate thread i cannot get the timer's output into my JtextArea called attArea.  i understand i am not referencing the instance of my Gui class which causes the problem, but i do not know how to fix my code so i can.  i have even tried instantiating my timer class inside the buildGui method belonging to Gui class.  that way compiles and the timer is running i think because the exit on close from the Gui does not give me a new prompt on the command line, so the timer must still be running on it's own thread.  however it is not printing in the attarea.  below is my code(3 classes)

```
 class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     new Gui();
     new TimerTest();
   }
  }
```

next class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Gui extends JFrame{
  int fieldWidth = 20;
  String[] choose = {"Choose"};
  JPanel pnlBack = new JPanel();
  JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel citiesPanel = new JPanel();
      JLabel citiesLabel = new JLabel("Cities: ");
      JComboBox citiesBox = new JComboBox(choose);
      //citiesBox.add("choose");
    JPanel typePanel = new JPanel();
      JLabel typeLabel = new JLabel("Type:  ");
      JComboBox typeBox = new JComboBox(choose);
    JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
      JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
      JComboBox nameBox = new JComboBox(choose);
  JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel attPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextArea attArea = new JTextArea(12, 50);
  JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel gasPricePanel = new JPanel();
      JLabel gasPriceLabel = new JLabel("               Price of gas: ");
      JTextField gasPriceBox = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
    JPanel mpgPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel mpgLabel = new JLabel("           mpg of vehicle: ");
        JTextField mpgBox = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
    JPanel moneyPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel moneyLabel = new JLabel("        Money you have:");
        JTextField moneyBox = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
    JPanel costPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel costLabel = new JLabel("                  Cost of trip: ");
        JTextField costBox = new JTextField(fieldWidth);
    JPanel distancePanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel distanceLabel = new JLabel(" Distance you can go: ");
        JTextField distanceBox = new JTextField(fieldWidth);

Gui(){
    buildGui();
}

//method to buld the gui
void buildGui(){
    this.setSize(600,500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Travel Calc");
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
    //System.out.println("buiding the gui.");
    pnlBack.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlBack, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)); 
    midPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(midPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    midPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));  
    bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    //add back panel to Jframe
    add(pnlBack);
    //add panels to back panel
    pnlBack.add(topPanel);
        topPanel.add(citiesPanel);
            citiesPanel.add(citiesLabel);
            citiesPanel.add(citiesBox);
        topPanel.add(typePanel);
            typePanel.add(typeLabel);
            typePanel.add(typeBox);
        topPanel.add(namePanel);
            namePanel.add(nameLabel);
            namePanel.add(nameBox);    
    pnlBack.add(midPanel);
        midPanel.add(attPanel);
            attPanel.add(attArea);
    pnlBack.add(bottomPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(gasPricePanel);
            gasPricePanel.add(gasPriceLabel);
            gasPricePanel.add(gasPriceBox);
        bottomPanel.add(mpgPanel);
            mpgPanel.add(mpgLabel);
            mpgPanel.add(mpgBox);
        bottomPanel.add(moneyPanel);
            moneyPanel.add(moneyLabel);
            moneyPanel.add(moneyBox);
        bottomPanel.add(costPanel);
            costPanel.add(costLabel);
            costPanel.add(costBox);
            costBox.setEditable(false);
        bottomPanel.add(distancePanel);
            distancePanel.add(distanceLabel);
            distancePanel.add(distanceBox);
            distanceBox.setEditable(false);

        // add connection method goes here  
        // new TimerTest();
 }
}
```

3rd class

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class TimerTest {

static int counter = 0;

public TimerTest(){

      TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Gui.attArea.append("TimerTask executing counter is: " + counter );
            //System.out.println("TimerTask executing counter is: " +      counter);
            counter++;//increments the counter
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");//create a new Timer

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 3000);//this line starts the timer at the same time its executed
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the reference of `Gui` to the `TimerTest` class

```
class TimerTest {

    static int counter = 0;

    public TimerTest(final Gui gui) {

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                gui.attArea.append("TimerTask executing counter is: " + counter);
                ...
            }
        };
        ...
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        new TimerTest(gui);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you create a document, and want a friend to read the document. What do you do? You give him the document, right?

Same with Java objects: you have a GUI, and you want the Timer to access the GUI. So you give the GUI to the timer:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gui theGui = new Gui();
        new TimerTest(theGui);
    }
}
```

Now the TimerTest constructor receives the gui that it will have to access. It just needs to keep a reference to this gui in a field:

```
public class TimerTest {

   private Gui theGui;

   public TimerTest(Gui gui) {
       this.gui = gui;
   }

   ...
}
```